# Acer Aspire E17 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS doesn't shut down/restart

Tags: server, 22.04, shutdown, acer, aspire

I have a fresh install of **Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS** on my spare Acer laptop, the only problem is that if I shut down/restart the laptop with the respective commands, it says:

> Reached System Reboot/Shutdown Target

but it doesn't turn off.

If I force-shutdown it after it reached this state (and restart it), everything works fine (no data loss) but it annoys me that if I shut down my laptop per SSH or by locally doing it, I have to power it down manually.
Does anyone have a solution?

System Specs:

- Model: *Acer Aspire E17*
- OS: *Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS*
- Graphics card: *Intel HD Graphics + Nvidia GeForce 840M*
- CPU: *Intel Core i5*
- RAM: *8 GB*
- Storage: *125 GB SSD + 1 TB HDD*

Comment: Can you see any errors in the system logs? `$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep 'Error' `

Comment: [Here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/acer-laptop-won%27t-shutdown-normally-4175531755/page2.html#post5307548) someone has an Acer Laptop too with the same issue which was solved.

Comment: @kladerradatsch I updated my Grub with the Options but it didn't help.

Comment: @kladderradatsch Here is my syslog: ```Dec 31 14:36:44 tqserver kernel: [    1.066769] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
Dec 31 14:38:55 tqserver canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[3345]: Error in livepatch check state: needs-check.
Jan  1 14:25:13 tqserver kernel: [    1.091739] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized. (x5)``` (I shortened the log because it's repetitive)